# Input type=search in Purecss framework

Tags: css, html, search, input

Here's input type="search" in it's natural habitat:

```
<input type="search" value="asd" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u9c7p345/

It has an X icon/button on the right side which is visible when there is text entered in the field.

When using the PureCSS framework, the default browser styling is over-written, and the [X] button which removes the text entered is not there anymore.

http://jsfiddle.net/fonfv7sL/

Can you point me to the file or CSS line that removes this specific browser default so I can amend the code?

Comment: `It has that X button when you hover or focus it.` um what? what system are you using? i dont see any X button

Comment: Latest Chrome on win 8.1. Example image: http://www.html5tutorial.info/images/input_type_search.png

Comment: im pretty sure the "natural habitat" has no "X". That x is added by your system and/or browser and/or plugins. I can only guess PureCSS resets all these custom wizardry and thats why you see it in its truly "natural habitat" state, without X.

Comment: take a look on "css reset rules". when you start making a website, "reset" your css so you have the same basic look across all systems. Then, based on that, you start designing your css so your design look is consistent across all systems.

Comment: to anyone reading this question and the answer below: this question ended up in a completely different direction, it wasnt clear from start what was the op's wish.

Answer (score 1):

As i already said in question comments, this X is being added by your system. In order to have this functionality consistent across all browsers, the first step you need to perform is some actions to negate this wizardry, you need to "reset" your css. About these "X"'s:

---

To remove “X” from all search input fields in IE, simply add this to bottom of your css:

```
input[type=text]::-ms-clear {  display: none; width : 0; height: 0; }
input[type=text]::-ms-reveal {  display: none; width : 0; height: 0; }
```

To remove “X” from search input field on Chrome Browser (and all it’s mutations), simply add this to bottom of your css:

```
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-decoration { display: none; }
```

The following CSS code should remove that clear button on all search fields on page:

```
input[type=text]::-ms-clear {  display: none; width : 0; height: 0; }
input[type=text]::-ms-reveal {  display: none; width : 0; height: 0; }
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-decoration { display: none; }
```

source: http://geektnt.com/how-to-remove-x-from-search-input-field-on-chrome-and-ie.html

---

you may also wanna disable that glow shadow thingy around the input field when is selected with

```
input {outline:none;}
```

---

now, you have the same look across all systems. now you can build from here the stuff you want, like a "X" across all systems.

So to answer your questions:

**Q:What does the PureCSS override that makes the button disappear?**

A:Because it probably resets the css, like the way i described.

**Q:How do I get it back while keeping the framework?**

A:If you want this functionality, you need to create it from scratch so it works for all browsers. Try using a absolute positioned on right div with "X" background on every input when input gets focus.

**(NOT) LATEST EDIT:**

After your last comment, im answering your question:

**Q:how to keep this for the browsers that support it and continue using PureCSS:**

A: You need to edit the .css file of PureCSS, search for all "input" rules that look like the ones i showed you above, and remove them.

**(hopefully :P ) LATEST EDIT:**

Q:how to keep this without changing PureCSS because i am serving it from CDN i can't edit

A: you need to re-apply the default values for the CSS that was reseted. See the default values here [how can I revert webkit-appearance for input[type="search"] of normalize.css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569161/how-can-i-revert-webkit-appearance-for-inputtype-search-of-normalize-css)
Be careful, they must be declared AFTER the PureCSS, so you may wanna have them inline after the PureCSS or an external css file after the PureCSS.

Comment: Well it's already taken care of by the PureCSS framework. Now I'd like to get it back for the systems that support it.

Comment: please clarify your question. do you need this X for all systems OR just for only for the systems that natively support it?

Comment: Only those who already support it. If I start building one for myself it's bound to not work on some x device and will possibly look ugly instead of not being there at all.

Comment: @user1340531 look on my updated answer. you just need to remove these css rules from that PureCSS file, and it will work.

Comment: @user1340531 use a CSS code beautifier to make the CSS readable to the human eye, then search and find any of these "-decoration" etc stuff on inputs and remove them.

Comment: I need to use CDN for the framework so I can't edit it

Comment: Used code from http://davidbcalhoun.com/2012/more-fun-with-webkit-pseudoelements-webkit-search-cancel-button-or-pseudoclass-inception/ Thanks for all the help

Comment: @user1340531 you do understand the code you posted is nowhere near what you finally asked for? This RESETS these X's and re-creates them **just like i adviced you in my answer.**

Comment: also that is for webkit only

Comment: Well I understand it recreates it, but since the selector is ::-webkit-search-cancel-button:after I figured it still only applies to browsers that support webkit-search-cancel-button and wont show up on anything else. Whereas recreating it by making a span and positioning it to overlap the input and adding js to make it work as a clear button could be bad.

Comment: @user1340531 please make sure your questions in future are better defined. your question ended up in a completely different direction.